# Filtering Max Number of Votes each party got for each year in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables each containing `election_id` `election_year` `election_type` (which is a `string`), `party_name`(also a `string`) `party_ID`, and the last one has `Results_ID`(equal to election_id) `Results_party`(equal to `party_ID`) and lastly `ballots`, my query has to return max number of ballots each party has ever gotten for the years in consideration for example(also desired output):

| Name | Year | Ballots |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Party A | 2000 | 105 |
| Party B | 2000 | 95 |
| Party C | 2004 | 50 |
| Party C | 2008 | 50 |

I tried this

```
SELECT Party.party_name,Elections.election_year,Results.Results_ballots
FROM ((Elections 
INNER JOIN Results 
   on Elections.election_ID=Results.Results_Elections 
   AND Elections.election_Type='Regional') 
INNER JOIN Party on Party.party_ID=Results.Results_Party)
```

but this gives me all the parties and all the elections with all the ballots, I want max ballot count for each one
any ideas are appreciated, I'm very new to MySQL

EDIT: also tried this, which missed the last row of the table

```
FROM Party as p, Elections as e, Results as r
where p.party_ID=r.Results_Party and e.election_Type='Regional'  AND r.Results_Elections=e.Elections_ID
group by p.party_name
```

So it looked like this

| Name | Year | Ballots |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Party A | 2000 | 105 |
| Party B | 2000 | 95 |
| Party C | 2004 | 50 |

Comment: Please check [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions-and-modifiers.html) in the docs.

Comment: show us your desired output

Comment: @eshirvana the desired output is the one I put on the original post

Comment: @astentx I actually did and got pretty close but it's missing an entry, the last one on the original post to be precise, which  is of the same type just a different year, so it should take those with equal number of ballots too

Comment: @Klaudio you want to do 2 groups, `GROUP BY p.party_name, e.election_year`

Comment: @Breezer it results in the full table still, with all the years and multiple ballot entries

Comment: @Klaudio did my answer work for you`??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have to do a subquery to get the max for each party.

this is what I came up with

```
SELECT * FROM Party c
LEFT JOIN Results b
ON b.Results_party=c.party_ID
AND b.ballots=(SELECT MAX(d.ballots) FROM Results d WHERE d.Results_Party=c.party_ID)
LEFT JOIN Elections a
ON a.Elections_ID=b.Results_ID
```

Comment: This gets the rows right but I can't seem to group it by the columns of interest, the rows are there tho

Comment: Ok now I got the columns, it still says it's failing one test, but I suspect the tests I've been given are janky. But it seems fine to me. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.